# Как лучше подойти к кроссбраузерной верстке?

Tags: css, кроссбраузерность

Ситуация: есть проект, который кто-то писал до меня. Я ничего не знаю насчет того как и где его тестировали, но волею случая мне надо в нем подкорректировать кроссбраузерность. В принципе ситуация не очень криминальная, в каждом браузере криво отображается небольшое количество элементов страниц. Но я кроссбраузерностью раньше не занимался и сейчас буду писать не с нуля. Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше организовать работу? В каком порядке писать и тестировать? Может есть по этой теме хорошие книги или источники информации? В гугле я путного ничего не нашел.

Comment: Сбросить все дефолты в ноль и максимально прописывать все свойства "руками"

Comment: Попробуйте для начала [автопрефиксером](https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/) пройтись, вдруг проблемы решит

Comment: @DNS в проекте я уже обнаружил reset.css,который обнуляет дефолтные стили браузеров.что касается "прописывать руками",то тут уже все сделано,просто работает в некоторых браузерах отдельные элементы не так как надо.то есть в данном случае вопрос правильной организации контроля и правок имеющихся стилей...

Comment: @Crantisz спасибо,попробую.он добавляет в стили необходимые для кроссбраузерности параметры?

Comment: @Iga да. И убирает лишние.